# Xamarin.ios Refresh Button

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I have a UiTableView that I want to reload when a button is clicked inside the navigation bar that looks like a refresh button.

I have the following setup its already connected via action to the display:

```
    partial void refreshButtonClicked(MonoTouch.Foundation.NSObject sender){


    }
```

But from here I want to reload the table data. Im stumped, I have tried to use table.Refresh()to no joy and I can not find any literature.

Help much appreciated

Comment: It would be good if you would include the code where you change your data. The common command for refreshing the table view is `ReloadData()`, but you may need to change the data in your `TableViewSource` first.

Answer (score 4):

You should use table.ReloadData()

Also take a look at [Populating a Table with Data](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/tables/part_2_-_populating_a_table_with_data/)

Comment: Can you detail how I would do that, I can call that inside this refreshButtonClicked.

Comment: Did you wrote you own datasource for tableview? Take a look at http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/tables/part_2_-_populating_a_table_with_data/

Comment: Yeah I did, do I do that here?

Comment: So on ReloadData method, make sure that the sourcedata (for example string[] items, as in example) is also updated, because if not, then at all after ReloadData you will not see any changes. So for example I pass into the TableViewSource parent view controller instead with public array of data that I use for my table